# Determine if a website sets a cookie

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

Using `HttpWebRequest`, how can we determine if the requested URL is attempting to set a cookie?

Also, how can we determine if any child elements (for example Google Analytics/third party iFrames) are attempting to set cookies?

Comment: If you use a `WebRequest` and not something like a WebBrowser component, you won't find out anything about what JS or iframes do, because they won't be downloaded or executed. `WebRequest` just downloads a file, it doesn't understand it's HTML.

Comment: does `HttpWebRequest.Headers` collection contain `Cookie`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to read the HTTP headers to check for a Set-Cookie header. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie.

This won't pick up any cookies being set via JS or anything else executed in the browser but if the server is setting a cookie this should pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cookies set by a response by looking at [the aptly named `Cookies` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies.aspx).